# Rails send e-mail in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the snippet below running in my Rails app, but it's not iterating properly:

```
task.users.each do |user|
  mail(to: user.email
       from: "Company <task." + user.id + "@mail.company.com",
       subject: "Update on " + user.assignment)
end
```

If there's 3 users, it only sends out one e-mail.  I've verified that there aren't any errors preventing it from continuing.

I can't simply pass an array of e-mails to the `to` option because I need to use the user's data in each iteration.

Can this be done like the above?

Comment: This should work as long as you really have three users for this task and all fields are populated as you expect.  Time to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `.deliver_now` method.

```
mail(to: user.email
       from: "Company <task." + user.id + "@mail.company.com",
       subject: "Update on " + user.assignment).deliver_now
```

I have run into an issue where this kind of delivery doesn't work, possibly because the mail was falling out of scope.

So you may need to do something like this:

```
class SendWeeklySummary
  def run
    User.find_each do |user|
      UserMailer.weekly_summary(user).deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

[Rails Guides docs - see section 2.1.4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails)

Comment: I can't iterate over the users in the mailer?

Comment: I think I tried that in the past and it didn't work, as I mentioned in the answer. That was Rails 3, so it may work with Rails 4... Besides, the mailer is not really the right place to iterate over users.